# Android locationlistener doesn't work on android device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location, listener

My location listener works when I am using the DDMS controls in the emulator but when I deploy it onto the phone it no longer works. My code is as follows

```
public class hoosheerAndroidAct extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    MapController mc;
    public static MapView gMapView = null;
    GeoPoint p = null;
    static double latitude, longitude;
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen1);

        // Creating and initializing Map
        gMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        p = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                (int) (longitude * 1E6));
        gMapView.setSatellite(true);
        gMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mc = gMapView.getController();
        mc.setCenter(p);

        mc.setZoom(11);
        myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, gMapView);
        gMapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        list = gMapView.getOverlays();
        list.add(myLocationOverlay);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 5.0f,
                this);

    }
```

methods implemented for `implements LocationListener`

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                    (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
            mc.animateTo(point);
            connect("http://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat="
                    + location.getLatitude() + "&geolong="
                    + location.getLongitude());
            Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
            gMapView.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker));

        }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

Is there anything I am missing? :-(

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's it doing differently on the device vs on the emulator?

Comment: @DHall When I run it on the emulator I can simulate the locations in the DDMS, when deployed to the phone it sets the coordinates to be (0,0)

Comment: I dont see where you assign a listener for the location... Also just so you know, in java you can write 1000000 as 1E6, dont put long numbers there if they can be shortened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps will default to network location provider if the GPS is unable to find a signal so that test could return a location without a GPS signal. I would recommend GPS Status as a good free app. The only other thing I can think of is to make sure you have a clear view of the sky.

Comment: I will have to try outside in the morning :-) why does it not work indoors?

Comment: The short wavelength of the signals broadcast by the satellites are unable to penetrate dense matter...such as a house or lots of coniferous trees.

Comment: still no success on finding the user location, it's putting me at coords (0,0) :-(

Comment: I think you should simplify your code or create a new simple program that displays the user's position onLocationChange. That way you can identify what part of the code is causing this problem. Sorry I don't have a simple answer :/

Comment: Just checking- are you on the Equator south of Greenwich? :)

Answer (score 0):

its because when your device is not able to find location it return default location 0,0. better you check your device gps connection by checking other apps like map app of your device

Comment: @Sunil I have checked the inbuilt maps which picks up the user's current location

Comment: have you notice joxTraex comment, plz insert your locationlistener assignment code

Comment: right now i don't have device so i can't not test your code, but try to change requestLocationUpdates to lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                this);

Comment: @Sunil I have tested the changes on numerous devices but still no success :-( what is the result in using that rather than what I initially had?

Comment: i think range will be an issue. in my case when i was testing my device in company i was not getting location. but when i get outside my gps provider was updating location. your map application may be showing last known location.

Comment: @Sunil I have since tried it again and it still does not work, it initially places me at the position (0,0) and then crashes out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are testing in door,can't get gps information. try to change LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER-->LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and try everything in programming. I read about that google use same other sensors to find location. I even find mobile where location listener won't work in google maps. When I checked the settings i accedently turn on battery power saving and location listener starts. On some other device where location wan't work too I turn on buttery saving and location is shown. I don't know why is that, but buttery maybe will save your app.